# Since a ListView in Flutter is stateless, how come it can be changed?

Tags: listview, flutter, statelesswidget

This is more of a philosophical question, I think, and the title pretty much says it all. It *seems* like a contradiction, that a ListView derives from stateless, and yet can be changed while the app is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListView` itself is not changing. You are simply rebuilding it with new information when you use a `StatefulWidget` with the call `setState()`. Thus the `ListView` never holds or changes state, you just are creating a new `ListView` with different starting information every time it changes.

Comment: Right, setState() triggers build(), and since I'm making my ListView in build(), it gets recreated. Got it, thank you! I am still thinking imperatively, where once you've built your UI it never changes.

Answer (score 2):

ListView doesn't change any value internally.
It has a builder, or children, and both of them are already specified when the build method comes up.

Statefull widgets are different, they let you change the state of some variable, or in general the state of the widget itself.